# Unit testing MongoDB.Driver dotnet core

Tags: .net, mongodb, .net-core, tdd, moq

We are using a Command/Query pattern where the implementation has detailed knowledge about how MongoDB works and we want to write a test for that. Mocking MongoDb `IMongoCollection<CarDocument>` while also making sure the correct `Find` filter is sent is quite challenging. We are using .NET core 2.1 and MongoDB.Driver v2.7.2

```
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace Example
{


    public class SomeMongoThing : ISomeMongoThing
    {
        public IMongoCollection<CarDocument> GetCars()
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("ConnectionString");
            var database = client.GetDatabase("DatabaseName");
            return database.GetCollection<CarDocument>("CollectionName");
        }
    }

    public interface ISomeMongoThing
    {
        IMongoCollection<CarDocument> GetCars();
    }

    public class GetCarQuery
    {
        private readonly ISomeMongoThing someMongoThing;

        public GetCarQuery(ISomeMongoThing someMongoThing)
        {
            this.someMongoThing = someMongoThing;
        }

        public CarDocument Query(string aKey)
        {
            var schedules = someMongoThing.GetCars();

            var match = schedules.Find(x => x.AKey == aKey);
            return match.Any() ? match.First() : this.GetDefaultCar(schedules);
        }

        private CarDocument GetDefaultCar(IMongoCollection<CarDocument> schedules)
        {
            return schedules.Find(x => x.AKey == "Default").First();
        }
    }
}
```

We have a test here but we are unable to write a test which checks that the correct `aKey`-filter has been used, meaning if we use the filter `x => x.AKey == "hello"` in the implementation the test should fail. Even if the code has `.Find(x => true)` the tests pass.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Example
{
    public class GetCarQueryTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void ShouldGetByApiKey()
        {
            var mockCarDocument = new CarDocument();
            var aKey = "a-key";

            var result = Mock.Of<IAsyncCursor<CarDocument>>(x =>
                x.MoveNext(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()) == true
                && x.Current == new List<CarDocument>() { mockCarDocument });
            var cars = Mock.Of<IMongoCollection<CarDocument>>(x => x.FindSync(
                It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<CarDocument>>(),
                It.IsAny<FindOptions<CarDocument, CarDocument>>(),
                It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()) == result);

            var someMongoThing = Mock.Of<ISomeMongoThing>(x => x.GetCars()() == cars);
            var getCarQuery = new GetCarQuery(someMongoThing);

            var car = getCarQuery.Query(aKey);

            car.Should().Be(mockCarDocument);
        }
    }
}
```

How would you test the provided code?
If making the abstraction between `SomeMongoThing` and `GetCarQuery` helps things we are open to suggestions. The idea is that the Query has knowledge about MongoDb to be able to leverage the power of the MongoDb client, and that the user of the query does not have to care.

Comment: Include what is currently happening with the code you provided.

Comment: I am curious why such a leaky abstraction was chosen?

Comment: I just ran this test and it passes as expected when asserted.

Comment: I have updated the example to explain more details, and am looking forward to suggestions. No matter how you abstract some part of your code will handle MongoCollection, how do you test that class?

Answer (score 2):

This, in my opinion appears to be a leaky abstraction as part of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

From comments

> No matter how you abstract some part of your code will handle MongoCollection, how do you test that class?

I wouldn't test that class. The class that ultimately wraps the collection would not need to be unit tested as it would simply be a wrapper for a 3rd party concern. The developers of MongoCollection would have tested their code for release. I see the whole mongo dependency as a 3rd party implementation concern.

Take a look at the following alternative design

```
public interface ICarRepository {
    IEnumerable<CarDocument> GetCars(Expression<Func<CarDocument, bool>> filter = null);
}

public class CarRepository : ICarRepository {
    private readonly IMongoDatabase database;

    public CarRepository(Options options) {
        var client = new MongoClient(options.ConnectionString);
        database = client.GetDatabase(options.DatabaseName);
    }

    public IEnumerable<CarDocument> GetCars(Expression<Func<CarDocument, bool>> filter = null) {
        IMongoCollection<CarDocument> cars = database.GetCollection<CarDocument>(options.CollectionName);
        return filter == null ? cars.AsQueryable() : (IEnumerable<CarDocument>)cars.Find(filter).ToList();
    }
}
```

For simplicity I've renamed some of the dependencies. It should be self explanatory. All Mongo related concerns are encapsulated within its own concern. The repository can leverage all the power of the MongoDb client as needed without leaking unnecessary dependencies on 3rd party concerns.

The dependent query class can be refactored accordingly

```
public class GetCarQuery {
    private readonly ICarRepository repository;

    public GetCarQuery(ICarRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public CarDocument Query(string aKey) {
        var match = repository.GetCars(x => x.AKey == aKey);
        return match.Any()
            ? match.First()
            : repository.GetCars(x => x.AKey == "Default").FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

A happy path for the above class can now be simply mocked in an isolated unit test

```
public class GetCarQueryTest {
    [Test]
    public void ShouldGetByApiKey() {
        //Arrange
        var aKey = "a-key";
        var mockCarDocument = new CarDocument() {
            AKey = aKey
        };

        var data = new List<CarDocument>() { mockCarDocument };

        var repository = new Mock<ICarRepository>();

        repository.Setup(_ => _.GetCars(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<CarDocument, bool>>>()))
            .Returns((Expression<Func<CarDocument, bool>> filter) => {
                return filter == null ? data : data.Where(filter.Compile());
            });

        var getCarQuery = new GetCarQuery(repository.Object);

        //Act
        var car = getCarQuery.Query(aKey);

        //Assert
        car.Should().Be(mockCarDocument);
    }
}
```

Testing actual Mongo related concerns would require an integration test where you would connect to an actual source to ensure expected behavior.

Comment: Great improvements to the original code! It does not answer the initial question on how to unit test with a mocked IMongoCollection, in your example how to unit test `CarRepository`. And if mocking is completely not recommended, how would you write a self-contained integration test, would it spin up an in memory db? how?

Comment: @DanielIgnat I am saying that I would not unit test `CarRepository`. I do not need to unit test 3rd party dependencies. It would be a waste of my time as its developers would have already tested it. As for integration testing, your current implementation is hard-coding connection information, but with the abstraction you can create your own implementation of the repository that connects to another data source for testing. There really is no need to mock Mongo related concerns here.